# Thingworx war 8.1 not setting up on tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat8, thingworx

I am trying to set thingworx 8.1 war on the tomcat server . I have configured the JAVA_OPTS in the catalina file as :

```
set "JAVA_OPTS= %JAVA_OPTS% -Djava.library.path=path-to-tomcat-webapp\Thingworx\WEB-INF\extensions"
```

I have also tried the setenv batch file approach also by setting the file as follows :

```
set LD_LIBRARY_PATH=path-to-tomcat/webapps/Thingworx/WEB-INF/extensions/
```

But still I am getting an error in the application log of thingworx as follows:

```
Failed to load FlxCore library. Ensure it's in PATH (Windows) or LD_LIBRARY_PATH(other platforms) or set with the VM arg, -Djava.library.path. Error message : com.flexnet.licensing.DllEntryPoint.entry([B)I
```

I am really stuck . Please help me out!!!

Comment: Is the issue resolved? Did you check the application logs from <Thingworx install directory>\ThingworxStorage\logs\ApplicationLog.log ?

Comment: The issue was with the license file and correcting that solved the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please verify that you have a relevant `license.bin` in **ThingworxPlatform**.

Comment: The issue was with the license . Corrected that and the error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure in the Tomcat Java Options field, has the following to the end of the options field:

```
-Dserver -Dd64
-XX:+UseG1GC
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-Djava.library.path=<path to Tomcat>\webapps\Thingworx\WEB-INF\extensions
```

Comment: I had exported the ld_library_path and there I had set the path to the webinf/thingworx/web-inf/extensions. The issue was with the license file. I corrected that and the issue was gone.